# How to fix Express.js application in docker that already running but doesn't accessible?

Tags: docker, express

I have built an application using `Express.js` and `Prisma` as its ORM.

I am trying to run my application using Docker, and after Expose it in the container, I want to access it locally using `docker run -p 3001:3002 klinikpintar/ttv:1.0`.

In docker desktop (GUI), it is already executed as the picture is shown below:
[image]

But it can't be accessed either when I accessed the endpoint using my browser (Firefox and Chrome) or Postman.

---

Here is my dockerfile:

```
FROM node:16-alpine
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json /usr/src/app
RUN npm install
COPY . .
ENV PORT = 3002
EXPOSE 3002
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Here is the snippet of my package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon server.ts",
    "start": "npx tsc && cd dist && node server.js",

    "build-docker-image": "docker build -t klinikpintar/ttv:1.0 .",
    "docker-image": "docker run -p 3001:3002 klinikpintar/ttv:1.0"
},
```

Notice that I transpile the typescript to javascript

---

Here is my snippet of `server.ts`

```
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

But in the terminal, it written like this: `Server is running at http://localhost:= 3002` (not `http://localhost/3002`) [I don't know whether it is relevant, but I write this in case it is]

Comment: Specify in your app that node should listen to all network interfaces: `app.listen(port, "0.0.0.0", ....)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're incorrectly setting `ENV` in the Dockerfile.  You need to delete the extra spaces in the `ENV PORT` line

```bash
ENV PORT=3002
#       ^ no extra spaces here
```

Dockerfile [`ENV`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env) has two syntaxes

```bash
ENV NAME=value
ENV NAME value
```

Since you have extra whitespace, it actually looks like the "name space value" layout

```bash
ENV NAME value
ENV PORT = 3002
```

This matches what appears in your diagnostic output: the variable `port` is set to the string `= 3002`.  I'm not totally sure how Node will handle that value – I might speculate it [listens on a Unix socket](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v18.x/docs/api/net.html#serverlistenpath-backlog-callback) – but it doesn't have the effect you want.